# Are Android Thread methods implicitly synchronized?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

In [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyL4AUBbB2w), at time 7:58, it looks like the variable `running` is being set to `true` in one thread and read in a different thread without explicit synchronization.

**Is there some magic that Android's flavor of Java does that makes this operation safe, or is the video misleading its viewers about safety?**

Let's set aside the issue of inefficient busy-waiting for the main UI thread for the moment and just focus on the correctness.

Comment: No. AFAIK Android does not do such thing. It works because on thread that read `running` variable, little discrepancy data does not affect rendering canvas too much.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara, That is an acceptable answer if you want to post it as such. I'm just trying to get a sanity check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In Android you still need to do proper thread synchronization.

The code in video may work because even though there is data discrepancy  between time when `running` variable is written in one thread and read on other thread that drawing canvas, it does not affecting canvas rendering too much as drawing one or more animation frames may not be visible to human eye.